# What is an example of a limit point that is not a cluster point?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My book said:

> 4.3.1. DEFINITION. A point $x$ is a limit point of a subset $A$ of $R^n$ if there is a sequence $(a_n)^∞_{n=1}$ with $a_n ∈ A$ such that $x = \lim_{n→∞} a_n$. A set $A ⊂ R^n$ is closed if it contains all of its limit points.

> A point $x$ is a cluster point of a subset $A$ of $R^n$ if there is a sequence $(a_n)^∞_{n=1}$ with $a_n ∈ A \text\ \{x\}$ such that $x = \lim_{n→∞} a_n$. Thus, every cluster point is a limit point but not conversely.

But I can't seem to find an example of that.

What is an example of a limit point that is not a cluster point?

Comment: How do you define limit point?

Comment: I agree with @Ennar ... to provide such a counterexample, we require the definitions of both conditions.  Maybe, after you write them both down, you will be able to answer this yourself.

Comment: Hay guys, I edited my post, and I still don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number $0$ is a limit point of $\{0\}$ but not a cluster point of $\{0\}$. Can you see why?

Comment: I think that I am getting it.

Answer (score 1):

The key difference in definitions is that for $x$ to be a limit point, you can take a sequence in whole of $A$ that converges to $x$, but for cluster point you can only take a sequence in $A\setminus\{x\}$. One immediate consequence is that for limit point you can take constant sequence $a_n = x$ if $x\in A$, but you can't take constant sequence for cluster point, you need to have other points around it. So, to find a limit point that's not a cluster point, we need a set that contains a point with no other points from the set around it, *isolated point*. For example, take $A=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$. All points in $A$ are limit points, and all points in $A\setminus\{2\} = [0,1]$ are cluster points, but $2$ is a limit point that's not a cluster point since there is no sequence in $[0,1]$ that converges to 2.